# An Acrobat PDF file must see in a thumbnail-like image

Tags: delphi, acrobat, bitmapimage, delphi-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF thumbnails in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010880/pdf-thumbnails-in-delphi)

I'm developing in Delphi 6 an application to show some Adobe Acrobat files BEFORE send to the Acrobat Viewer, just like a thumbnail.

Can you help me providing me with some code to show the file in a TImage, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this question [PDF thumbnails in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010880/pdf-thumbnails-in-delphi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See QuickPDF http://www.quickpdf.org/ and [PDF thumbnails in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010880/pdf-thumbnails-in-delphi)